# To use Apple's game servers, do I need to enroll in the Apple Developer program?

Tags: game-center

I am developing a multiplayer iPhone game. To use the Apple game servers, do I need to register for the Apple Developer program?

Comment: We don't just "give code"; if you run into a specific problem, we answer questions. As such, I am removing the code request from your question.

Comment: Apple doesn't offer game servers last I checked, just Game Center achievements and leaderboards, for which you'd have to register for.

Comment: @ChrisMcFarland, it would be good if you could provide a source, but it sounds like you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @ChrisMcFarland Apple does support through Game Center turn-based games.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. "Game Center" services are on [the list of services](https://developer.apple.com/programs/whats-included/) included with an Apple Developer Program membership, as is App Store Connect, which is needed to manage various back-end aspects of some Game Center features, such as [leaderboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH7-SW10) and [matchmaking](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH12-SW2).

Note that the "servers" Apple provides are only for these services. No part of Game Center involves Apple hosting your actual game server process. They just supply "meta" services like leaderboards, achievements, matchmaking, and so on.